# Differential Equation with power over derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am solving this $$u^{''}+u+\epsilon u^3=0$$
where $ u(0) =1$ and $u^{'}(0)=0$
I tried this
$$u''u'+uu'+\epsilon u'u^3=0$$
$$\frac{d(u')^2}{2}+\frac{d(u)^2}{2}+\epsilon\frac{d(u)^4}{4}=0$$
Integrating both side
$$\frac{(u')^2}{2}+\frac{u^2}{2}+\epsilon\frac{u^4}{4}=c$$
where c is some constant.
but I do not have idea how to solve with power over derivative. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This question did not explicitly ask for an approximate solution which was asked in the linked question. And the answers in the linked post also do not mention that there is a "closed form" solution using Jacobi's elliptic function.

Comment: @MrYouMath:  Yes, I know.  The words "exact duplicate" have an idiosyncratic meaning on math.stackexchange.com!

Comment: cf. this article on the [Poincaré-Lindstedt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Lindstedt_method) perturbation method.